# how to access the node api from a remote page in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

In my electron app , I load the remote page(index.html) from remote url like("http://xxxx/index.html"), then I am trying to send a ipc event to the main process then handle it , and failed, but if I put the the index.html in local fs and it is OK.

So my question is how to enable the page to access the node api (like require,ipc, etc.) from the remote page.

------    (main process)

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadUrl('http://localhost:8080');
  //mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
var ipc = require('ipc');
  ipc.on('spawn-ext-process', function () {
  console.log("spawn-ext-process");
});
```

--------- http://localhost:8080/index.html (render process)

```
<script>
    var ipc = require('ipc');
    ipc.send('spawn-ext-process');
</script>
```

Comment: Even with Electron, you can't have access to node in a remote page. That would be extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

AFIAK the ipc api doesn't use http. It essentially is sending a signal from one part of the program running on your local machine to another part of the same program on that machine.

If you want to send a signal over http you might want to use something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) or [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Answer (score 3):

> How to enable the page to access the node api (like require,ipc, etc.) from the remote page?

Depends on how you're loading the page. If you're using `loadUrl` on a `BrowserWindow` instance, node integration is enabled by default (you can disable it via the `nodeIntegration` option, see the [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md)).

If you're using a `<webview>` tag, then it's disabled by default and you can enable it via the `nodeintegration` attribute. See the [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/096b94857029c45ed0f2e492f3759e757b986c6f/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#nodeintegration). Note that with `webview` you can preload scripts that do have access to node and electron APIs safely, and then access to those objects are destroyed when the script has finished executing (see [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/096b94857029c45ed0f2e492f3759e757b986c6f/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#preload)).

Like @FelipeBrahm said, I would not give a remote page access to node.js or electron APIs unless it's your own page, and even if you do that, be cautious.